# How to read all file with specified ext in a dir?

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs and want this to work.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir("dir", function(err, files) {
    if (err) return;
    files.forEach(function(f) {
        data = []
        if f.extension = "rtf"
        data = data + f.data
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.readdir("dir", (err, files) => {
    if (err) return;
    files.forEach(f => {
        let data = []
        const ext = path.extname(file)
        if (ext == ".rtf") {
            fs.readFile(f, function read(err, content) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                data.push(content);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You will have each content of the files under the array `data`. But it will be better to put it into an object to know where the content come from like this :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.readdir("dir", (err, files) => {
    if (err) return;
    files.forEach(f => {
        let data = {}
        const ext = path.extname(file)
        if (ext == ".rtf") {
            fs.readFile(f, function read(err, content) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                data[f] = content;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. I am novice. I tried your code and then searched about fs module. I think I got it. Just need to add utf8 as I want to open it as text stream.