# Node windows path difficultas

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running this simple code. from here [How to read all file with specified ext in a dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767874/how-to-read-all-file-with-specified-ext-in-a-dir/36769675?noredirect=1#comment61148074_36769675).

this is the ttst.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.readdir("PLR", (err, files) => {
    if (err) return;
    files.forEach(f => {
        var data = []
        const ext = path.extname(f)
        if (ext == ".rtf") {
            fs.readFile(f, 'utf8', function read(err, content) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                data.push(content);
                Console.log(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I am getting error path not found.

```
C:\Users\rahulkumar.patel\Desktop\ttst.js:12
                    throw err;
                    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\Deskto
p\11.txt'
    at Error (native)
```

11.txt is file in plr folder.

So it is identifying each files in plr but while doing something its ommiting the dir plr itself. Path really problematic in node windows.

I also tried similar solution but the same problem. fs.readfile omiting dir. How to give exact directory.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir("\htmls", function(err, files) {
    files
         .filter(function(file) { return file.substr(-5) === '.html'; })
         .forEach(function(file) { fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', function(err, contents) { 
         if (err) throw err;
         inspectFile(contents); }); });
});

function inspectFile(contents) {
    console.log(contents);
}

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\scripting.filesystemobject\Deskto
p\Default.aspx.html'
    at Error (native)
```

the path should be
C:\Users\scripting.filesystemobject\Deskto
    p\htmls\Default.aspx.html

Comment: should const ext = path.extname(files) be const ext = path.extname(f)?

Comment: My mistake. But problem remains.

Comment: sorry what is `PLR`?

Comment: how are you running the application and in which directory ? `PLR` should be in `\` .

Comment: It is catching the path of plr which is on desktop the same folder as ttst.js file. However while readFile omits the \plr\